# Subversion for iSeries

Tags: svn, version-control, ibm-midrange

We need info about Subversion for iSeries (OpenSource version).
Has anyone used it for production systems?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: If you can make SVN run on a folder on pc.  (I can) you can make SVN run on a folder on the AS400.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam,

How are you planning to use it?  If you want to connect WDSC or RDi to it for project management then that could work.  Unfortunately if you want to use it on the green screen it may not do it for you since iSeries source code is stored in database files typically rather than text files in the IFS.

All that SoftLanding has done is port it, not add any additional utilities for managing iSeries source code.  Therefore by itself the main use is maybe managing files in the IFS or talking to remote clients like WDSC, RDi, TortoiseSVN, etc.

However, Aaron Bartell has done some work to extend this functionality... see [http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/ibmi/april08/developer/19751p1.aspx](http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/ibmi/february08/developer/19751p1.aspx) and http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/ibmi/april08/developer/20214p1.aspx.  I'm not sure if he has done any further work since then.

Also you might check out his website at http://mowyourlawn.com/.

I'm working towards implementing something like this, but so far haven't had enough time to get it done.  Personally I have to deal with multiple programmers and I'm not sure about Aaron's approach working too well for that.  If I get any further I'll update my answer here.

Good luck!

Brandon

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on Subversion for OS/400 from Softlanding but their Turnover product is top notch.  They understand change management on the iSeries.  Their Subversion should be a good product.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wriong, but the last I heard, SoftLanding is no longer maintaining the opensorce subversion product.