# How to use Subversion on AS400 (iseries)

Tags: svn, ibm-midrange

First of all I am a beginner to AS400.

I am working on an application whose development environment is setup on AS400 machine and I am working as a remote user. Right now I have to manage development and code versioning, separately. So first i develop a code and then i have to manually update it to my SVN through my local machine. Also for deploying code on testing environment (on same server but in separate directory) i have to manually paste code changes to files.

I can not do development from my local machine, as there are some AS400 programs called from the script which will not run properly.

I have tried searching for setting up SVN client on AS400 machine itself so that i can directly run SVN commands through console and deploy the code on testing environment but no luck.

Please suggest if SVN client can be setup on AS400 or not. Also any help on different type of development environment would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1038532/62576

Comment: Searching for "AS400" topics might not get good results since "AS400s" haven't been marketed since around 2002 or so. Use "ibm i subversion" or "ibm i svn" for more current results. The platform is far past what "AS400s" used to be.

Comment: What is the application written in?   At a bare minimum you can ask your system administrator to set up IFS access as a network share.  That helps a lot.

Comment: SVN for IBM i is available from http://www.softlanding.com/solutions/websphere/subversion-download/   Looks like it is still free.  Your system administrator will need to install the server side parts.

Comment: Thanks for the information but i am looking for SVN client software for IBM i. In the provided link i could see subversion software for IBM i but client softwares are for windows etc. Please help!!